# Keep newlines after split

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I have the following code, it splits my file that has 4 columns to separate
files. the last column "loses" his new lines.
How can I keep them?

```
for line in routeFile:
    if line.__contains__("internal"):
        # split the line into a list of columns values
        fields = line.split()
        if len(fields) >= 2:
            print(fields[1], file=file_hosts)   # Prints the 2nd column - the hosts
        if len(fields) >= 3:
            print(fields[2], file=file_domain)  # Prints the 3rd column - the domain
        if len(fields) >= 4:
            print(fields[3], file=file_apps)    # Prints the 4th column - the apps
```

EDIT:
This is my file, I need the apps column to stay exactly as it is (With the newlines between the apps)

```
> space       host                 domain              apps    
> abc    cloudconfiguration   cfdev.internal                
> abc    globalbootstrap      cfdev.internal    globalbootstrap          
> abc    tenant-management    cfdev.internal
> abc    uaa-management       cfdev.internal 
> abc    tenant               cfdev.internal    tenant
```

Comment: Why not just add a `print()` call? `str.split()` explicitly strips the string of leading and trailing whitespace, so yes, the `\n` newline is no longer part of the `fields`, this is intentional.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I think you mean `strip()` there

Comment: @cricket_007: why would that be?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Because `split()` splits on whitespace (which includes leading, trailing, and inner whitespace) but `strip()` "explicitly strips the string of leading and trailing whitespace"

Comment: @cricket_007 So? The *result* is that there is no leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Fair point

Comment: You misunderstood me, I want to keep the new lines. not remove them

Comment: Please don't call magic methods directly if you don't have to.  The `__contains__()` method is meant to be used by the `in` operator: `'internal' in line` instead of `line.__contains__('internal')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly add the newline again:

```
for line in routeFile:
if line.__contains__("internal"):
    # split the line into a list of columns values
    fields = line.split()
    if len(fields) >= 2:
        print(fields[1], file=file_hosts)   # Prints the 2nd column - the hosts
    if len(fields) >= 3:
        print(fields[2], file=file_domain)  # Prints the 3rd column - the domain
    if len(fields) >= 4:
        print(fields[3] + '\n', file=file_apps)    # Prints the 4rt column - the apps
```

Comment: I want to keep the original new lines the as it was before I took it out from the file.

Comment: @Yafit Why? A newline is a newline.  Should not matter if you use the one in the file or the one added in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the fields with empty strings so there are always four values in that list, even if there are fewer columns in the row:

```
for line in routes_file:
    if 'internal' in line:
        fields = line.split()
        fields.extend([''] * (4 - len(fields)))
        _space, host, domain, app = fields
        if host:
            print(host, file=hosts_fime)
        if domain:
            print(domain, file=domains_file)
        print(app, file=apps_file)
```

This way there will be empty lines in the apps file for empty cells in the apps column in the input file.  This does not apply to the other two files.  If those also should have empty lines for empty cells in the corresponding columns you have to remove the `if`s for them too.

Answer (score -1):

This is my working solution:

```
for line in routeFile:
    if line.__contains__("internal"):
        # split the line into a list of columns values
        fields = line.split()
        fields.extend(line.split())
        fields.append('\n')
        if len(fields) >= 2:
            print(fields[1], file=file_hosts)   # Prints the 2nd column - the hosts
        if len(fields) >= 3:
            print(fields[2], file=file_domain)  # Prints the 3rd column - the domain
        if len(fields) >= 4:
            print(fields[3], file=file_domain)    # Prints the 4th column - the apps
```

Comment: Why the `extend()`? And the appending of the newline doesn't have any effect in the shown code. Both lines could be deleted from the program.